# Asp.net webform intranet site on IIS 10, keep ask for user and password

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've an asp.net webforms application running on our intranet (same Active Directory).

I want to auto authenticate .

So i'm using on my C# code :

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
```

to get user name and doing some stuff.

In my web.config i'm not specifying any authentication mode.

In IIS 10.0 in default website and also in virtual directory i've

[image]

The problem is that from my development PC it works well, but from any other pc's of my organization, Windows keep continue to ask for user and password.

What can it be ?

Thanks

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 First, read IIS log files to see what kind of 401 you hit.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the reason why you achieve the auto authenticate  for your web application is the IE security setting.

[image]

If your customer doesn't enable this setting, the IE browser will not auto send the username and password to the server to login in the user. So you will face your customer need to type in the username and password.

To solve this issue, you should suggest client side to enable the security setting to auto login in.

More details about how to enable the auto log in you could refer to below steps:

1.Open the IE and find the internet options.

[image]

2.Modify the user authentication

[image]